# What happened with daniel hogan´s space dive prosecution?

Tags: united-states, court

I just read that the red bull strato project actually was the idea of Daniel Hogan. When he noticed, that red bull wanted to start it years later, he went to court. But what happened then? Was he get payed?

Comment: @NateEldredge please don’t answer in comments

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Bull_Stratos) has a link to an [archived press release](https://web.archive.org/web/20111227014738/http://www.redbullstratos.com/JumpOnHold.aspx), dated June 30, 2011, announcing that the case had been settled out of court.

I didn't find any further details, but that's not surprising because such settlements typically include a confidentiality agreement.  It's likely that Hogan received some sort of payment, but there's no way to know how much.